# next.config.json rewrites for vercel deployment to flask

Tags: next.js, vercel

With using Vercel, what do my fetch and CORS ip's need to be changed to?

I have a next.js frontend and flask backend. I have opened 2 ports opened through my router as virtual servers (previous arrangement. Vercel omits the one of the ports).

I have ran then both locally fine by providing my public ip as a dns for my domain name and making post requests to it; configured flask's cors origins with it as well.

js fetch example:

```
    try {
  const response = await fetch('http://<my_public_ip>:<backend_port>/<endpoint>', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });
```

flask CORS config:

```
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/submit_form": {"origins": [
"http://<my_public_ip" ]}})
```

The post requests are not going through, now that Vercel required me to change my domain dns to it's generated ip.

Error: "CORS request did not succeed"

I've toiled with the error before, but I can not figure out what it wants now.

Have also included rewrites to the next.config.js. Which just increased the probability of failure...

```
    const nextConfig = {
  pageExtensions: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/:path*',
        destination: 'http://<my_public_ip>:<backend_port>/:path*',
      },
    ];
  },
};
```